# Не добавляется элемент в DictionaryLiteral

Tags: словари, swift4

Есть такой фрагмент кода:

```
typealias UniqueContacts = DictionaryLiteral<Int64, String>
var uniqueContacts: UniqueContacts = [:]
uniqueContacts[123456] = "Raisa Ivanovna"
```

Компилятор ругается на 3 строку: `Cannot assign through subscript: subscript is get-only`

`var` - говорит компилятору, что словарь `mutable`, но при этом не разрешает добавить пару ключ/значение

Почему так происходит?

Как это побороть?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разобрался.

`DictionaryLiteral` - всегда `immutable` словарь.

А вот просто `Dictionary`, объявленный через `var` - `mutable`